# Read json put it into list

Tags: python, json

I am new at the coding. I am trying to read json file and reach some values then put them into list.

I tried;

```
with open('score.json', 'r') as f:
    score = json.load(f)

def match():    
    r_=score["r"]    
    for r in r_:    
        t_a=r["types"]    
        for types_d in t_a:    
            v_a=t_d["v"]    
            for v_d in v_a:    
                key.append(v_d)    
key=[]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I got this error. Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Reading from json gives you a dictionary. What do you want to do with that dictionary?

Comment: Either kscore or r or t-d(i'm leaning towards r or t_d) is a list, not a dictionary. You are trying to look a value up by key in a list

Comment: I will convert it to dataframe and merge with other dataframes according to "key" and "name" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you put here is a list not a dict. when you load this JSON to kscore make that a list in the first line of match function you tried to get "r" attribute of that and error says you can't do that. to solve the problem make the JSON like a dict like below:

```
{"numberOfHits": 2, "results": [{"groupName": "annotation", "totalHits": 12, "types": [{"type": "reference", "approximateCount": 9, "values": [{"key": "GO_REF:0000052", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:19203586", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:20333297", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:10983986", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:14749367", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:16792529", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:20878056", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:21045808", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:25190803", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}, {"type": "assignedBy", "approximateCount": 3, "values": [{"key": "UniProt", "percentage": 75.0, "hits": 9, "name": null}, {"key": "HPA", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": null}, {"key": "MGI", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}, {"type": "goId", "approximateCount": 8, "values": [{"key": "GO:0005886", "percentage": 25.0, "hits": 3, "name": "plasma membrane"}, {"key": "GO:0005737", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": "cytoplasm"}, {"key": "GO:0032991", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": "protein-containing complex"}, {"key": "GO:0005634", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": "nucleus"}, {"key": "GO:0005654", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": "nucleoplasm"}, {"key": "GO:0005829", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": "cytosol"}, {"key": "GO:0015630", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": "microtubule cytoskeleton"}, {"key": "GO:0031982", "percentage": 8.333333333333332, "hits": 1, "name": "vesicle"}]}, {"type": "taxonId", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "9606", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 12, "name": "Homo sapiens"}]}, {"type": "evidenceCode", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "ECO:0000314", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 12, "name": "direct assay evidence used in manual assertion"}]}, {"type": "geneProductId", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "UniProtKB:P31749", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 12, "name": null}]}, {"type": "aspect", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "cellular_component", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 12, "name": null}]}]}, {"groupName": "geneProduct", "totalHits": 1, "types": [{"type": "reference", "approximateCount": 9, "values": [{"key": "GO_REF:0000052", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:19203586", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:20333297", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:10983986", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:14749367", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:16792529", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:20878056", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:21045808", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "PMID:25190803", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}, {"type": "assignedBy", "approximateCount": 3, "values": [{"key": "UniProt", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "HPA", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}, {"key": "MGI", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}, {"type": "goId", "approximateCount": 8, "values": [{"key": "GO:0005886", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "plasma membrane"}, {"key": "GO:0005737", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "cytoplasm"}, {"key": "GO:0032991", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "protein-containing complex"}, {"key": "GO:0005634", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "nucleus"}, {"key": "GO:0005654", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "nucleoplasm"}, {"key": "GO:0005829", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "cytosol"}, {"key": "GO:0015630", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "microtubule cytoskeleton"}, {"key": "GO:0031982", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "vesicle"}]}, {"type": "taxonId", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "9606", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "Homo sapiens"}]}, {"type": "evidenceCode", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "ECO:0000314", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": "direct assay evidence used in manual assertion"}]}, {"type": "geneProductId", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "UniProtKB:P31749", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}, {"type": "aspect", "approximateCount": 1, "values": [{"key": "cellular_component", "percentage": 100.0, "hits": 1, "name": null}]}]}]}
```

or get "r" like this:

```
r_ = kscore[0]["r"]
```

it's says get "r" property from the first elemnt of kscore.

---

The below code read keys from each type:

```py
with open('kscore.json', 'r') as f:
    kscores = json.load(f)
    for kscore in kscores:
        results = kscore["results"]
        for res in results:
            types = res["types"]
            for type in types:
                key = []
                values = type["values"]
                for val in values:
                    key.append(val["key"])
                print("{} : {} ".format(type["type"], key))
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives only limited result when I try to put in for loop to get all kscore[i] it gives error: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.

Comment: well loop raise an error because there are only one object in list, and what do you mean "It gives only limited result"? "results" property has only two object inside.

Comment: The file is way bigger, if you prefer I can try to upload it.

Comment: What's your purpose? do you want to put all the keys in values in "key" list?

Comment: yes, I want to put  them into list after  "values":. The bunch of lists like: {"key": "GO_REF:0000052", "percentage": 16.666666666666664, "hits": 2, "name": null}